# cannot load such file -- rufus-scheduler (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger, redmine, rufus-scheduler

While I do not want to exclude that I may be missing something very stupid, I did try to read all I could find on this topic, so here's my problem:

I am trying to run a rufus-scheduler in my redmine (2.6) installation, as described here: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineReceivingEmails#Schedule-email-receiving-with-Rufus-Scheduler

The host system is CentOS 7 x64 + Plesk 12.

`gem list` shows `rufus-scheduler (3.0.9)`

When restarting redmine, I get the following error log:

```
cannot load such file -- rufus-scheduler (LoadError)
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  /var/www/vhosts/klwr.de/redmine.klwr.de/redmine-2.6.1/config/initializers/emailhandler.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /var/www/vhosts/klwr.de/redmine.klwr.de/redmine-2.6.1/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:108:in `eval'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:108:in `load_app'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:27:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/share/gems/gems/passenger-4.0.59/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:26:in `<main>'
```

My first guess was that I need to apply one of the following directives to Apache:

```
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMinInstances 1
PassengerSpawnMethod direct
```

however, applying any combination of these just changes the error log so that an error does not occur in rack-loader but in rack-preloader.

Showing the bundle contents of redmine does not show the rufus scheduler. Could this be a cause? (if yes, this should be mentioned in some documentation on redmine).

Here's the complete content of the file config/initializers/emailhandler.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
require 'rufus-scheduler'

load File.join(Rails.root, 'Rakefile')

ENV['host']='xxx'
ENV['port']='25'
ENV['username']='xxx'
ENV['password']='xxx'
ENV['project']='xxx'
ENV['unknown_user']='accept'
ENV['no_permission_check']='1'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
# Check emails every 1 mins
scheduler.in '1m' do
  task = Rake.application['redmine:email:receive_imap']
  task.reenable
  task.invoke
end
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this + for any hints. Have a great day.

Comment: It is strange that authors recommend to install gem directly without `bundler`. I know when Redmine starts it can see only "bundled" gems. It means that I recommend you to add a line `gem 'rufus-scheduler'` to `Gemfile`, run `bundle install` and try to start Redmine again.

Comment: @gotva please paste it as an answer. It works :)

Answer (score 3):

It is strange that authors recommend to install gem directly without `bundler`.

I know when Redmine starts it can see only "bundled" gems. It means that I recommend you to add a line

```
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
```

to Gemfile, run `bundle install` and try to start Redmine again.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue for me echo "gem rufus-scheduler" >> Gemfile